# Statistical significance for response rates

Tags: statistical-significance

I am trying to determine whether my response rates for a survey are statistically significant or not. I haven’t done an A/B type test. I just have response rates as a function of time or month.. I also have count of surveys sent and surveys responded—how do I determine if the response rates are statistically significant or not? There are so many tests out there like p,z,t, anova but I am not sure what to use..

I am also very new to statistical significance.

Comment: The statistical significance follows the test of a null hypothesis. What is your null hypothesis?

Comment: To answer that question— I am trying to determine if there are particular months showing a statistically significant difference in response rate.. so if I am not mistaken my null hypothesis would become that there are no months showing a statistical significance difference in response rates?? But I am not sure What kind of test to run for this to see if there is a particular month that is significant in terms of the response rate and responses received.

Comment: "response rates for a survey", "count of surveys sent and surveys responded". Are 3 "survey" the same thing? If yes, what it is?

Comment: Yes they are the same. I have three columns.. one is the count of surveys sent. The other is count of surveys received. And third is response rate which is just responded/sent.

Comment: This is somewhat tangential to your main question...I think @user158565 was hoping you'd distinguish among different ways in which "survey" might be used.  E.g., to mean the entire research enterprise; an instrument; or a form submitted by a particular respondent.

Comment: Your first comment nicely narrows down and defines what you are looking for.  Try looking up the chi-square test and the test of the difference between independent proportions.

Comment: Oh gotcha..I think it’s to look at the entire research enterprise rather than looking at a form submitted by a particular respondent... does that clarify? Apologies I am super new with marketing research and statistics..

Comment: Oh wait for the purposes of the data I have— it is a sub-division of a division that I want to check statistical significance for so maybe that’s makes it an instrument...??